# Using 2 points to find gradient in log-log plot

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, structural-engineering

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiUlK.png

Dear all, the gradient of log log graph of equation highlighted in pink is 2. The question is since the scale is log-log, we can take 2 points highlighted in green as gradient that is (1-0.01)/(100-10)=0.011 and why is not 2. What mistake or misconception I have made?

Thank you and have a nice day !

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the image instead of a link to the image. This way people don't have to follow a link to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With log log plots, the distance on the graph is the log, not the value.  If you calculate out the slope for your numbers, you get:
$$
\text{slope}
=
 \frac{
   \log_{10}{\left(1\right)}
   -
   \log_{10}{\left(0.01\right)}
 }{
   \log_{10}{\left(100\right)}
   -
   \log_{10}{\left(10\right)}
 }
= \frac{0 - \left(-2\right)}{2 -  1}
= 2.0
\,.
$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks, mate !! Forgotten hahaha